# can someone help me with the code for this function?

Tags: javascript, function, code-snippets

Hello so i have to do a function that when i call it has to show me the Student information and i have to call it getInfo so i tried something like this but i don't know what code i have to put for the function:
Can someone help me:

```
class Student {
    Name
    Adress
    Phone
    Course 
    Constructor(Name,Phone,Adress) {
       
    }
}
var Name= "Stefan"
var Adress= "Strada Campia Islaz numarul 50"
var Phone="+40766334455"
var Course="Curs Javascript"
function getinfo(Name, Adress, Phone,Course) {
    
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class

Comment: that's just for class info

Comment: Yes, but it contains examples and structures you'll need when you're working on your homework. We're not here to give complete tutorials or copy-paste answers to homework questions.

Comment: Should the function _return_ the information to some calling code, or actually _show_ it on screen? If so where/how should it show it? Your question is too vague and also have you tried _anything_? Also not clear why you defined the function with input parameters if the idea is to fetch that same info, not input it? Was that deliberate, or just some random guesswork on your part? Is the function supposed to be part of the class? (Currently it isn't.)

Comment: Actually, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) maybe is a better reference.

Comment: yeah i see what you mean but i'm just wondering what i should write for the function to give the information that i wrote in that class like i have to a function called getinfo that gives me a list of information about that student you got any way to help me?

Comment: A list? You mean an array? Or an object? Or a formatted HTML string? Be **specific**. Also it's unclear where you're stuck. What part of the task puzzles you? Have you tried anything? You didn't answer the rest of the questions I asked either. We're here to help you, but part of that involves you explaining things clearly to us and showing us that you've at least made a reasonable attempt at it first.

Comment: i mean a list with the information about the student or person like when i call the function getinfo it has to show me: Name Adress Phone and Course of that person or student.Is there any way i can do that?

Comment: classic gimme code question

Comment: A template must be created to create Student objects. Each Student must have the following properties:

name

address

phone

course

Each object that represents a student must have the following behavior (method):

getInfo ()

The getInfo () method must, as a return value, return the accumulated data about a student (for example, Name: John Benson, Address: High Park 36, Phone: (507) 833-3567, Course: Geography).

Constructor functions and prototypes or classes can be used in creating templates for creating objects. Choose the approach that suits you best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
class Student {
  constructor(name, adress, phone, course) {
    this.name = name;
    this.adress = adress;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.course = course;
  }

  getInfo() {
    console.log(this.name);
    console.log(this.adress);
    console.log(this.phone);
    console.log(this.course);
  }
}

var newStudent = new Student('Stefan', 'Strada Campia Islaz numarul 50', '+40766334455', 'Curs Javascript');
newStudent.getInfo();
```

Comment: So i have to do that for every person or student?

Comment: yes, newStudent1, newStudent2 and then newStudent1.getInfo() and newStudent2.getInfo() and so on.

Comment: please check it as done or upvote. So I will get some points. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The class should hold the function as a class method. I'm not sure how you'll end up writing your code, but here's an example:

```js
class Student {

  // The student data is passed in as an object
  // and we assign each property to the new instance
  constructor(obj) {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => this[k] = v);
  }
  
  // getInfo simply returns the type
  getInfo(type) {
    return this[type];
  }

}

const data = {
  name: "Stefan",
  address: "Strada Campia Islaz numarul 50",
  phone: "+40766334455",
  course: "Curs Javascript"
};

// Create a new student instance from the class
// passing in the data object
const student1 = new Student(data);

// Call the getInfo function with the type
console.log(student1.getInfo('name'));
console.log(student1.getInfo('course'));

const data2 = {
  name: "Jo",
  address: "Mars",
  phone: "+85435435",
  course: "Acupuncture 101"
};

const student2 = new Student(data2);

console.log(student2.getInfo('name'));
console.log(student2.getInfo('course'));
```